# SharePoint 2007: Delete Links in DVWP and Reloading Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

I have a document library data view web part and I enabled the editing link options for the 'delete'.

I can delete the document successfully but after that some of my other webparts disappear. so I need to refresh my page to get them back.

How can I reload the page after I deleted a document? using the below code?

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete={',$KeyField,'=',$KeyValue,'};__commit;'))}">delete</a>
```